# significance tests for mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, split-plot

I have a two-factor split-plot design experiment looking at biomass across a large region and in the presence or absence of fire. Biomass is measured in 5 different forests and each forest has two fires that differ in age. Each fire has a paired set of 3 control plots, except for one forest which has only 3 control plots. Control and fire pairs are assigned as "site".

I've set up a mixed model to examine treatment effects with three fixed effects: forest, fire, and their interaction. I included a random intercept to help account for between-site variation in biomass that wasn't due to forest differences or differences from fire.

```
lmer(bio ~ forest * fire + (1 | site))
```

The interaction is what I'm interested in, i.e., within a forest, does fire cause a significant decrease in biomass? Does that differ between the fire ages? I've read a little that suggests that a t-test on the fixed effects terms can help me answer this, e.g., if the estimate for forest A x fire 1 interaction is significant, I can conclude that fire 1 had a significant effect on biomass in forest A. Is this true?

Comment: Do you maybe have an example of what your data looks like, or perhaps a figure of the study design? I'm having trouble following what is nested in what. Also, what does the age of a fire mean?

Comment: Maybe you can share (a link to) the data (or some mock-up)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a little more clarification may be needed, but I think I understand what you want to look at.

The first step will be investigating whether or not the interaction you have specified in your model is significant. This is generally done with a likelihood ratio test, and can be done using the following code in R.

`m1 <- lmer(bio ~ forest * fire + (1 | site))
 m2 <- lmer(bio ~ forest + fire + (1 | site))
 anova(m1,m2)`

This will tell you if this interaction leads to a significantly better model fit.

If the interaction improves model fit, you can do some pairwise comparisons to investigate how the different levels of your factors affect your outcome variable. I would recommend looking into the package `emmeans`.